# Convert Logical Partition to Primary

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, hard-drive, partition

I have a very simple, yes or no question, hopefully.  I have a logical partition inside of an extended partition, along with some free space in the extended partition.  On server 2008 r2 if I drop the logical partition inside of the extended partition will I be able to also drop the extended partition and then create a new primary partition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will lose all data in the old partitioning scheme*.

*: From a data-recovery perspective, at least at first, the data's still there, but it won't be accessible; it'd be like deleting a file.

Comment: Great, I forgot to mention I have already done my backups ;)